# Java Android BluetoothAdapter Override?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estou desenvolvendo um app que utiliza a classe BluetoothAdapter... ela não funciona do jeito que eu preciso. Porém eu fui tentar dar uns Override na classe, porem ela não permite.

Quando passamos por parâmetro o BluetoothAdapter, Na verdade estamos passando uma String de um local, certo ?

```
Intent intent =  new Intent("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE");
```

or

```
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE;
```

Com isso ele, retorna para o usuário, uma pergunta se ele deseja ativar o bluetooth, eu preciso editar que assim que apertar no Botão, não perguntar e já ativar, Como seria o override de uma classe desse tipo ? como editar ? como fazer o bluetooth ativar sem perguntar se ele realmente deseja ? é possível ? se não, eu sou o desenvolvedor porque não é possível ? '-'

Comment: Não é possível por questões de segurança. Como utilizador de um celular android você gostaria que um programa ligasse o *Bluetooth* ou o *GPS* sem você saber?

Comment: A pessoa vai apertar o Botão pra ativar, sem precisar de exigir aquela message Box...  não tem nada a ver de  ativar sozinho. Você leu a minha pergunta ?

Comment: Como é que o SO Android sabe que você perguntou ao usuário se podia a ligar o *Bluetooth*?

Comment: oxi... essa é minha pergunta, quero dar Override ou qualquer outra função que permite reescrever... pra eu poder manipular isso, quero saber como fazer, eu quero que meu app garanta para o SO que foi feita a pergunta e foi confirmada... pegue seu celular e ativa o bluetooth, ve se ele retornou alguma pergunta :B